# Eclipse RCP: How are libraries in the bundle class path handled?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, classpath

I have an Eclipse RCP application with libraries in the bundle class path of the application. The MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
...
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
  libs/commons-io-2.4.jar,
  libs/gson-2.3.1.jar,
  libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar,
  libs/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar,
  libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
...
```

When the application is started (as exported product outside of Eclipse) these libraries are copied into the folder `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/13/0/.cp/libs`. Looking at the file attributes it seems that this is done with every application start (?). Is this behavior somewhere documented and can this be influenced (e.g. defining a custom folder from which these libraries are loaded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done when a plug-in is packaged as a Jar. `FileLocator.toFileURL` will temporarily unpack the jar to this location if necessary.

You can specify that a plug-in is packaged as a directory so that this does not happen using

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

as a entry in the MANIFEST.MF (see the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html))

**Note:** If your are using Features to build a RCP this is overriden by the `unpack` option of the `plugin` entry in the feature.xml